# Unable to generate a string

Tags: php

I have a group of 7 checkboxes as name="restriction[]" and value that I have assigned is Pos1 to POS7. Now I wish to generate string according to selected chechkboxes that is If 1st,5th, 7th boxes are selected it gives me sting as 1000101
if only first is selected it generate 1000000

My code is

```
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
for ($i=1;$i<count(restriction);$i++)
{   
if($restriction[i].checked)
{
    $val=$val+"1";
} else {
    $val=$val+"0";
}
}
echo $val;
}
```

but its gives me error where I have used if condition.

Comment: What is the exact error message?

Comment: 'for ($i=1;$i<count(restrictiond);$i++)'
 need to be: 'for ($i=1;$i<count($restrictiond);$i++)'

Comment: That's not PHP, but some PHP/JavaScript hybrid language that does not exist. Check your syntax and PHP manual. PHP does not have the dot operator in that sense and concatenation character is `.`, not `+` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make things easier with the following checkboxes and PHP:

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit'] == 'Submit') {
    //Take checked checkboxes and makes their indicies keys and their values 1
    $checkboxes = array_fill_keys(array_values($_POST['restriction']), 1);

    //
    $checkboxes += array_diff_key(array_fill_keys(range(0,6), 0), $checkboxes);
    ksort($checkboxes);
    echo implode('', $checkboxes);
}
?>

<form method='post' action='#'>
    <input type='checkbox' name='restriction[]' value='0' />
    <input type='checkbox' name='restriction[]' value='1' />
    <input type='checkbox' name='restriction[]' value='2' />
    <input type='checkbox' name='restriction[]' value='3' />
    <input type='checkbox' name='restriction[]' value='4' />
    <input type='checkbox' name='restriction[]' value='5' />
    <input type='checkbox' name='restriction[]' value='6' />

    <input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit' />
</form>
```

Or you could use for and and be boring!

```
<?php
if($_POST['submit'] === 'Submit') {
    for($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        echo (array_search($i, $_POST['restriction']) !== false) ? '1' : '0';
    }
}
?>
<form action="#" method="post">
    <input type="checkbox" name="restriction[]" value="0" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="restriction[]" value="1" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="restriction[]" value="2" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="restriction[]" value="3" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="restriction[]" value="4" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="restriction[]" value="5" />
    <input type="checkbox" name="restriction[]" value="6" />

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Comment: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: The output should be an `string` like `1000101`, not the sum.

Comment: @scessor It will be a string, because I casted the return from `intval()`.

Comment: @user168415 Which snippet gives you the error? Try placing `var_dump($_POST);` before everything and post its output here.

Comment: Strings are concatenated with `.`. `(string)intval('1')+(string)intval('2') === 3`.

Comment: See [tdammers answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7253581/problem-with-generating-string/7253599#7253599)

Comment: Yes, you are correct. In my haste, I completely ignored the fact I was using addition + assignment instead of concatenation. Thanks for catching my mistake @scessor Juhana

Comment: Please check answer by 'Tatu Ulmanen' but its giving me serialize string as 1100000 not according to position.

Comment: @user168415 The code snippet now works as expected.

Comment: @phpmycoder take me to the chat

Comment: @user168415 http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3020/chat-for-7253581

Comment: I don't have 10 reputation to talk..

Comment: I wish to do it using for loop.. check out answer by @scessor and also check my problem in comment.

Answer (score 3):

Learn the PHP language basics. The dot (`.`) does string concatenation, not member access. Member access is `->`.

Comment: Thats what I am learning. and after having problem with my assignment I have put it here.

Comment: If u think yourself as expert than Y don't u answer. Instead of commenting someone and devoting someone check yourself first. If it is really a easy question for you than answer it without any error.

Comment: @user168415 tdhammers can't upvote his own post. The three downvotes were probably form the 3 people that upvoted his post, not tdhammers himself.

Comment: @user168415: Please cut the attitude. I write PHP for a living, no need to challenge me. I'm trying to help you here, but rather than fix your code without explanation, I'm giving you a hint about where you might have gone wrong (in fact, I've told you exactly what your problem is and how to solve it). SO is not a "please do my homework" site, it's a public Q&A site, intended to be helpful to you and everyone else who might run into the same problem. You may also want to check your spelling / grammar, because the way you're writing makes you look immature and rude.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (isset($_POST["submit"])){
    for ($i=1; $i<count($_POST["restriction"]); $i++){   
        if($_POST["restriction"][$i]){
            $val .= "1";
        } else {
            $val .= "0";
        }
    }
    echo $val;
}
```

Comment: Its giving me string in series instead according to series of checkboxes selected..
like if 1st and 5th is select than it will give 1100000 and I wish to have like 1000100